# How to specify the target of one OpenGL ES texture

Tags: opengl-es

Got one OpenGL ES texture from other lib, want to specify its target.

```
// got from other lib, no more information about it's target, format..
void *a = foo();   

// glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, (uintptr_t)a);   
// or   
// glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, (uintptr_t)a);
```

Is there a convenient way to specify the target of this texture?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Your code shows `void *a = foo();`  How is the function `foo` declared?  Does it return a texture id, a pointer to texture data, or... what?

Comment: It's a texture id. The **a** is generated from the function **foo**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May find a temporary way:

```
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, (uintptr_t)texptr);
    if (glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR) {
        LOGI("texture target == GL_TEXTURE_2D");
    } else {
        LOGI("texture target != GL_TEXTURE_2D");
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, (uintptr_t)texptr);
    if (glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR) {
        LOGI("texture target == GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY");
    } else {
        LOGI("texture target != GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY");
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, (uintptr_t)texptr);
    if (glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR) {
        LOGI("texture target == GL_TEXTURE_3D");
    } else {
        LOGI("texture target != GL_TEXTURE_3D");
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0);

    // ... and so on
```